# Is it possible to use different connectors on MCollective client and server side?

Tags: puppet, activemq, mcollective

Is it possible to use the STOMP connector on client side and ActiveMQ on server side?
Here are my configurations:

```
#client.cfg
connector = stomp
plugin.stomp.host = localhost
plugin.stomp.port = 6163
plugin.stomp.user = mcollective
plugin.stomp.password = password  

#server.cfg
connector = activemq
plugin.activemq.pool.size = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.1.user     = mcollective
plugin.activemq.pool.1.password = password
plugin.activemq.pool.1.host = localhost
plugin.activemq.pool.1.port = 6163
```

After switching server to ActiveMQ mco ping doesn't get a response.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ broker supports a wide range of [transport connectors](https://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html), so as long as the broker has an [STOMP listener](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) defined, that configuration should be valid.

In your case, add a listener to the `TransportConnector` declaration in `/etc/activemq/activemq.xml` file, if you happen to use the PuppetLabs repository, or the appropriate configuration file for your broker otherwise:

```
<transportConnectors>
   ....
   <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
</transportConnectors>
```